# Create a list of dictionaries with unique keys from a list of dictionaries with duplicated keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries:

```py
records = [{id:123, name:'Course A', enrolled_date:'1st Feb'}, 
           {id:123, name:'Course A', enrolled_date:'1st Jan'},
           {id:456, name:'Course B', enrolled_date:'1st Jan'}]
```

I want to create a new list of dictionaries from this data. The new list should only contain dictionaries with `ids` unique within the scope of that list e.g.:

```py
new_records = [{id:123, name:'Course A'}, 
               {id:456, name:'Course B'}]
```

This is the code i've tried so far. It's obviously not working - but I've exhausted all efforts to correct it.

```py
new_records = []

for record in records: 
    new_id = record['id']
    new_name = record['name'] 
    new_dict = {'id':new_id, 'name',new_name}
    If new_id not in new_records:
        new_records.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: What happen to the `enrolled_date` key pair? Do you just want to drop that ?

Comment: @MooingRawr yes, i just want a list of course ids and names without duplicates

Comment: Based upon what you want to exclude duplicated observations?

Comment: You should have checked `if new_dict in new_records` :)

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the code you provided but it works really really slow for large list as noted in other comments.

```
new_records = []

for record in records: 
    new_id = record['id'] 
    new_name = record['name'] 
    new_dict = {'id':new_id, 'name': new_name}
    if not any(new_record['id'] == new_id for new_record in new_records):
        new_records.append(new_dict)
```

Comment: That was a typo - the code i've tried doesn't work even when using `record`. I've updated my code to remove the type red herring

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it by filtering the array using a set of already "seen" entries:

```
records = [{"id":123, "name":'Course A', "enrolled_date":'1st Feb'}, 
           {"id":123, "name":'Course A', "enrolled_date":'1st Jan'},
           {"id":456, "name":'Course B', "enrolled_date":'1st Jan'}]

seen     = set()
new_dict = [d for d in records if not(d['id'] in seen or seen.add(d['id']))]

# {'id': 123, 'name': 'Course A', 'enrolled_date': '1st Feb'}
# {'id': 456, 'name': 'Course B', 'enrolled_date': '1st Jan'}
```